# How to update an input field in cincom smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, input-field

When an input field depends on a real-time operation it fails to update after setting its new value
i.e.

```
inputfield1 setValue: 'state2'.
```

It seems like it awaits a screen refresher in order to do that.

So the question is, what does it take to update the display of an input field if the software sets the new value as oppose to the user?

Comment: What variant of Smalltalk are you using and what UI framework? Without that, this question doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I had to set the value by directly assigning to it as oppose to using the method setValue

```
inputfield1 value: 'state2'.
```